# Add a space after every character in VBS

Tags: string, vbscript, spaces

I want to have an input box, you type in a string and it gives you an output but there is a space after every character (even spaces).
Example:

```
"Hello There." → "H e l l o  T h e r e ."
```

Everything I've tried online never worked (I would get a lot of errors).

Comment: What person in their right mind up-votes this question? Enlighten me please, what makes this deserving of an up-vote?

Comment: Start with a `For` loop that iterates through the string characters for the `Len()` of the string and append a space? What exactly did you try that supposedly errored?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a space to every character without creating a column with them VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63838126/adding-a-space-to-every-character-without-creating-a-column-with-them-vbscript)

Comment: Looks like a dups, and solution is there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838810/632926

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get each character in a string using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1135826)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this function [Space](https://ss64.com/vb/space.html) : Return a string consisting of a specified number of spaces.

---

With the comment of @Lankymart you can write something like that in vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Input,i,OutPut
Title = "Add a space after every character in VBS" 
Input = InputBox("Hello There.",Title,"Hello There.") 
If input <> "" Then 
    For i = 1 To Len(Input) 
        OutPut = OutPut &  Mid(Input,i,1) & space(1) 
    Next 
End If
MsgBox OutPut,vbInformation,Title
Inputbox "The String " & chr(34)&  Input & chr(34) &" is converted to ",Title,OutPut
```

Comment: By answering this all you do is encourage others to ask the same poorly conceived questions. You should be flagging the question and moving on.

Comment: It also means it won’t Roomba now, so thanks for that.

Comment: It's a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838810/632926) of a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1135826/692942), you know that. So why are you so surprised?